# Using clojure.math.numeric-tower, or any library

Tags: math, clojure

I try to learn a bit of Clojure because the language looks nice.
But it seems that there is no info anywhere on how to install/use libraries like for example the clojure.math.numeric-tower.

For now I run the REPL by typing this in my Linux shell:

```
java -cp ~/Clojure/clojure-1.3.0/clojure-1.3.0.jar  clojure.main
```

I downloaded the numeric-tower jar, and put it everywhere. I have modified the -cp option in every possible way. I have put the numeric_tower.clj file everywhere.
It still doesn't work.

What's the way to use the libraries?

Comment: Hey, it's been years -- will you accept my answer?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had this same issue yesterday (also as a newcomer to Clojure). From my understanding, between Clojure 1.2 and 1.3 they split out many of the contrib libraries into separate projects so that they could be managed more easily. And shrink the core of what Clojure is.

The easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do is through leiningen (I got this answer from technomancy in the #clojure IRC channel yesterday evening). The recommendation is to create a "playground" project using leiningen that you can play around in and learn Clojure.

So, create a playground project with:

```
lein new playground
```

Modify the project.clj file to include:

```
[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.1"]
```

as a dependency. I was told that http://search.maven.org/ is the easiest way to find out which is the most up-to-date version of a particular library.

Then, run

```
lein deps
```

to pull in the jars. Now you're ready to

```
lein repl
```

to get going.

Once the repl is started, pull in numeric-tower:

```
(require '[clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math])
```

Then you can do your expt call:

```
(math/expt 4 6) ;; yields 4096
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: you can also do `(use '[clojure.math.numeric-tower])` and then drop the "math" part: `(expt 4 6)` => 4096

Comment: As a former Java programmer, this procedure for making sure that a library is available seems incredibly simple, and I'm happy that the clojure community has made it this simple.  As a former (well, current) Common Lisp programmer, this procedure seems incredibly complicated, and I'm surprised that the clojure community has not made it simpler.  (That's not an argument for CL over clojure.  Each has its costs and benefits.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all. It works now.
In fact the problem that really confused me was that java didn't understand the ~ (linux home) symbol after a colon in the classpath.
I was doing

```
java -cp ~/Clojure/clojure-1.3.0/clojure-1.3.0.jar:~/Clojure/lib  clojure.main
```

and java doesn't understand that.

However, if you do

```
java -cp ~/Clojure/clojure-1.3.0/clojure-1.3.0.jar:/home/username/Clojure/lib  clojure.main
```

it works.

Strange behavior of the classpath variable.

I would have used lein, but since I'm considering doing some programming for android, I thought it would be better if I could understand how all this work  with java only. Unless lein can package android project as well?

Anyway, thanks. All three replies were very informative.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to use libraries with just the Clojure CLI (**without needing to install an external tool** like `lein`) is:

1. In your current directory, make a file named `deps.edn`, and put the information about what library you want to use there. For example, to use the latest version of [`math.numeric-tower`](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower/) (which is 0.0.5, at time of writing), the contents of `deps.edn` should be the following:

   ```clj
   {:deps
    {org.clojure/math.numeric-tower {:mvn/version "0.0.5"}}}
   ```
2. run `clj` to start a repl. The first time you do this, you'll see that the required files are downloaded, and then you can use the library.

   ```
   $ clj
   Downloading: org/clojure/math.numeric-tower/0.0.5/math.numeric-tower- 0.0.5.pom from central
   Downloading: org/clojure/pom.contrib/0.2.2/pom.contrib-0.2.2.pom from central
   Downloading: org/clojure/math.numeric-tower/0.0.5/math.numeric-tower-0.0.5.jar from central
   Clojure 1.11.1
   user=> (require '[clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math])
   nil
   user=> (map math/sqrt (list 16 4))
   (4 2)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it directly in your classpath, like you're doing with clojure.jar.  If both were in the current directory, you would start clojure with

```
java -cp clojure-1.3.0.jar:numeric-tower.jar clojure.main
```

(or windows)

```
java -cp clojure-1.3.0.jar;numeric-tower.jar clojure.main
```

However, if that project is on clojars or in the maven repositories, its easier to use [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen). It can take a lot of the hassle out of that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had done this and the the REPL would't start (permission denied, or other strange "parse errors" etc...). Well, now, I downloaded the jar again and the REPL is running. However, (clojure.math.numeric-tower/expt 4 6) is giving me a class not found exception. I guess I should have used an import command, but there are too many of them. I don't understand what I should use: "require", "use", "import", "alias", "refer" with strange keys. That's too many choices for me.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

make lib folder

make under lib clojure/math

put file lib/clojure/math/numeric_tower.clj

java -cp .;lib;clojure-1.3.0.jar;lib/clojure clojure.main

repl

> (use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)